# Java Http POST with basic authorization and redirect

Tags: java, http, authorization

The program does a http post with basic authorization just fine but when the post is complete the page is redirected to a success page. The redirect failes due to 401 authorization failed.

```
        final URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " +base64);
        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

The line

```
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

fails due to 401 authorization failed...

I have also tried adding

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " +base64);
```

after

```
wr.flush();
```

I get the error of "Already connected". Evidently the authorization that I set doesn't follow over to the redirect. Any solutions to this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your call to `conn.connect()` after setting up the headers?

Comment: No need, conn.getOutputStream() connects automatically if no connection is already made.

Comment: Didn't realize that. Will have to go back and check the doc for `URLConnection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options you can try:

1. Use the `setDefaultRequestProperty` (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDefaultRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to set the Authorization header.
2. Disable automatic redirect following: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setInstanceFollowRedirects%28boolean%29 and do it manually.

Comment: 1. Deprecated. The instance specific setRequestProperty method should be used after an appropriate instance of URLConnection is obtained. Invoking this method will have no effect. And it was right it had no effect didn't even get past the post with that method. 2. The whole reason of the redirect is to find out if the response was successful or not so disabling the redirect will not do any good. If it was successful it will go to one page if not it will go to another.

Comment: If you disable the redirect you can still read the header using `getHeaderField` to check if a `Location` header is set: this will tell you if the login was successful.

Comment: Yes, that solution will work thanks. I will post the complete solution later. There has to be a bug with the sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection handling the 302 redirects and requests properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working solution for anyone else who has this problem. Thanks again to Femi for providing a workaround idea.

```
URL url = new URL(page);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " +base64);
wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();
if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP){
    url = new URL(conn.getHeaderField("Location"));
    conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "basic " +base64);
}
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```